# Angular Material: How to select table row by clicking only the checkbox?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have this angular material table with selection [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/xaammedjmvjn?file=app%2Ftable-selection-example.ts) from angular material website.

This table with selection allows you to select the table row by clicking the checkbox and any other space outside the checkbox but within the row.

What changes should I make to make selection of table row by only the checkbox?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove `(click)="selection.toggle(row)"` from the last `tr` it should be

```
 <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
  </tr>
```

instead of

```
 <tr (click)="selection.toggle(row)" mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
  </tr>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xmnbkz)

Comment: this works, thank you! I'm just wondering if removing that ```(click)="selection.toggle(row)"```  would affect the submission of the row data that are selected if say I have a button below the table that submits those selected row to the backend?

Comment: @kaiilim if should not have any affect on that you may give it a try